# Converting Hexadecimal to Decimal Without .parseInt();

Tags: java

I'm writing some code that converts from hexadecimal to decimal WITHOUT using built-in java functions like Integer.parseInt( n, 16);

Here is what I made, and it doesn't work:

```
    public static int hexToDecimal(String hexInput) {
    String hexIn = hexInput.replace("", " ").trim();
    Scanner hex = new Scanner(hexIn);
    int decimal = 0;
    int power = 1;

    while (hex.hasNext() == true) {
        String temp = hex.next();

        if (temp.equals("1") == true) {
            decimal += 1 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("2") == true) {
            decimal += 2 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("3") == true) {
            decimal += 3 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("4") == true) {
            decimal += 4 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("5") == true) {
            decimal += 5 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("6") == true) {
            decimal += 6 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("7") == true) {
            decimal += 7 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("8") == true) {
            decimal += 8 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("9") == true) {
            decimal += 9 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("A") == true) {
            decimal += 10 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("B") == true) {
            decimal += 11 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("C") == true) {
            decimal += 12 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("D") == true) {
            decimal += 13 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("E") == true) {
            decimal += 14 * power;
        } else if (temp.equals("F") == true) {
            decimal += 15 * power;
        }
        power = power * 16;
    }

    System.out.println(decimal);
    return decimal;
}
```

Could I have some help? It seems like it has some basic functionality, but it breaks with most input. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What breaks? Do you get an error message? If so, what do you get?

Comment: What happens is that the program runs without errors, but it does the calculations wrong. Like inputting 3A is supposed to output 58, but it actually outputs 163. Or ABC is supposed to output 2748, but it outputs 3258.

Comment: You should put that in your question.

Answer (score 4):

As you scan to the right, you are multiplying by progressively higher powers of 16. That's exactly the opposite of what you want. Try this logic instead, which is a bit simpler than what you're now doing:

```
public static int hexToDecimal(String hexInput) {
    int decimal = 0;
    int len = hexInput.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        char c = hexInput.charAt(i);
        int cValue;

        switch (c) {
        case '1':
            cValue = 1;
            break;
        case '2':
            cValue = 2;
            break;
        . . .
        default: // unexpected character
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-hex character " + c
                + " found at position " + i);
        }
        decimal = 16 * decimal + cValue;
    }
    return decimal;
}
```

It scans from left to right as you are now doing, multiplying the value of what's already been processed by 16 for each new hex digit encountered.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reverse input string because doing it your way most inportant digits are on the right side

put `hexInput=new StringBuilder(hexInput).reverse().toString();` to reverse sting
or simply do power other way like

```
int power=Math.pow(16,hexInput.length()-1);
```

and then at end of loop do

```
power/=16;
```

i would use second method, because you don't have to do extra code.